# How to update a column with values depending upon conditions - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My requirement is to update a column with 'Y' if a set of conditions are met or with 'N'. I want to do it in the same query.

For example :

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1 (COL1 INT, COL2 INT);

CREATE TABLE TAB2 (COL1 INT);

INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES(2, 3);

INSERT INTO TAB2 VALUES(1);

INSERT INTO TAB2 VALUES(1);
```

I want to update the COL2 of TAB1 with 'Y' if TAB1.COL1 matches with the TAB2.COL1 or COL2 should be updated with 'N'. This of course a simple example and the actual requirement far more complex.

Comment: Col2 is an int. You cannot fit 'Y' in there. Also, 'matching with tab2.col1' is a bit arbitrary. Which do you want to match with? Also, when you insert values in Tab1, the rows in Tab2 are not inserted yet. All in all, your question has some gaps on the specification level.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. Actually it should be a CHAR column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Corrected my answer to update 0 as well.

Assuming Y as 1 and N as 0 (since you said COL2 is INT)

```
UPDATE TAB1 T1
SET T1.COL2 = 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TAB2 T2 WHERE T2.COL1 = T1.COL1) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2dab2/6) is the SQLFiddle.